# C++ mini chat App

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, chat

so i'm trying to create a mini chat app, just to get into and understand socket programming and a thing or two about threads, i'm doing it with c++ Mfc, I can establish a connection between the client and the server (verified it with netstat) but as to the send and recv functions, i can't quite understand how it should be done, I send a message from the client app but the server doesn't seem to receive it

Server's Source code :

```
int RcvThread();
SOCKET s;
void CChat_ServerDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{

WSADATA w;

int error = WSAStartup ( 0x0202,&w);
if(error)
{
    OnCancel();
}
 if (w.wVersion != 0x0202) 
{
    WSACleanup ();
    OnCancel();
}
SOCKADDR_IN addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);
addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
s = socket ( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
     if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    OnCancel();
}
 if (bind(s, (LPSOCKADDR)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{

    OnCancel();
}
listen (s, SOMAXCONN);
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) RcvThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);

int buffsize = 1024;
char msg[1024] = "a";
int marker;
}

    int RcvThread()
    {
char sbuffer[256];

char buffer[sizeof(sbuffer)] = {0};

for(;; )
{

    if(recv(s, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer), NULL) > 0)
    {
        memcpy(&sbuffer, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer));
        MessageBox(hnd,sbuffer,"message",NULL);
    }
}

return 0;
    }
```

Client's Source code :

```
SOCKET s;
void CChat_ClientDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{

WSADATA wsadata;

int error = WSAStartup(0x0202,&wsadata);

 if (error)
{
    MessageBox("Error","ERRR");

    OnCancel();
}


if (wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202) 
{
    WSACleanup ();
    OnCancel();
}

SOCKADDR_IN target;

target.sin_family = AF_INET;
target.sin_port = htons(3124);
target.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

s = socket ( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    OnCancel();
}

   if (connect(s, (SOCKADDR *)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    OnCancel();
}
}
```

button sending message :

```
void CChat_ClientDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
char* Msg = new char[256];
Msg = "abdouabdouabdou";
send(s,Msg,256,NULL);
}
```

Comment: Since this question is tagged MFC it is surprising that you're not using the [`CSocket` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxzt95kb.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a fundamental concept of sockets. The listen socket (s in your code) is used to accept connection requests. It is not used for sending/receiving data. You have to create another socket for that. You need more study of documentation and samples. One source is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx

Also, your threading is improper. The thread function must match the signature specified for CreateThread, if you use CreateThread. But in an MFC app you should use AfxBeginThread instead of CreateThread.

Comment: First of all thank you, when using the recv function i read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx so i kinda supposed that the listen socket could be used to receive and send data, i saw other programs which used two sockets but i somehow ended up ignoring that, plus i'm still not used to working with msdn, it's kinda not linear enough for me

Comment: MSDN is reference material: Not the best for learning concepts. One good tutorial on winsock can be found at the winsock programmer's FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, believing that send() and recv() will send and receive *packets* is a common misconception. If you use TCP (which you should for a chat program) recv() could return any number of bytes between 0 and the buffer limit you specify. So if you send 256 bytes your recv() function could split this into two, three or more fragments of the message or it could return the end of the first message together with the beginning of a second one. What is frequently done is that the first n-byte of a message (n depends on what your maximum message size is) marks the length of the message. Since you limit your protocol to 256 bytes message length, 1 byte is sufficient. After receiving the first byte allocate a message buffer as large as your message and put recv() in a...well...receive loop until it has received the whole message. You need to juggle a bit with offsets into your receive buffer and the like.

Second, you didn't quite understood how the bind()/listen()/accept() system works. The listen() function sets the socket to passive mode in which it is listening for new clients. accept() finally establishes the connection to a new client and returns a *new* socket which is then used to communicate with the client. The original (listen)socket continues listening for new clients.

Third, your send function handles your char-buffers incorrect. I corrected it a bit with respect to my suggestion (first byte of message marks length of following message):

```
void CChat_ClientDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
  std::string myMessage = "abdouabdouabdou";
  unsigned char buffer[256];
  buffer[0] = (unsigned char)myMessage.length();
  memcpy(buffer+1, myMessage.c_str(), std::min(myMessage.length(), 255));
  send(s, buffer, 256, NULL);
}
```

Even that method is incorrect because send() returns the number of bytes sent which could be less than the size of my buffer, although that's a rare case for such small messages.

Comment: :/ yeah I totally hate getting into projects like that without the sufficient background, this afternoon i'm gonna do more reading and watch a couple detailed tutorials, thanks